# nodejs - change local variable value from within a event listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling

Im trying to set a variable from within event handler/listener/function

```
export async function mis() {
  let result; // <--------- LOCAL VARIABLE IM TRYING TO CHANGE (currently undefined)

  const m = await spawn(`/cmd`);

  m.stdout.on('data', function () {
    result = true; // <---------- HERE IS WHERE IM TRING TO CHANGE LOCAL VARIABLE (set to true)
  });

  return result; // -------- RETURNING undefined instead of true
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: That code executes sequentially, so it gets to the return statement before updating `result = true`

Comment: makes sense, thanks for pointing that out. is there a way around it... maybe wrapping it in a promise will work

Comment: Check [this](https://avtechstand.web.app/Promise%20and%20async-await/) link to understand how async/await works.

Answer (score 0):

As is currently written the code will executes sequentially and the function will not `await` the data and will reach the `return` statement before.

Using a Promise should work. Or you can also use `util.promisify()`

(Im not handling errors)

```
export async function mis() {
    let result; // undefined
    const m = await spawn(`/cmd`);
    const onData = new Promise((resolve) => {
        let data;
        m.stdout.on('data', function () {
            data = true;
            resolve();
        });

        m.stdout.on('end', function() {
            resolve(data); // resolve when the events end
        })
    })
    const res = await onData();
    return res;
}
```